# Material-kit-react problem in small screens when using two GridItem inside GridContainer

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

[image: GridItem problem with small screens]

So I'm trying out the library [material-kit-react](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit-react).

[<GridContainer>](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit-react/blob/master/src/components/Grid/GridContainer.js) containing just one [<GridItem>](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit-react/blob/master/src/components/Grid/GridItem.js) works perfect. But as soon as I add another <GridItem>, the first <GridItem> moves up, over the [<Header>](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit-react/blob/master/src/components/Header/Header.js) & out of the screen(only in very small screens).

Here is the code ([src/views/Components/Components.js](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit-react/blob/master/src/views/Components/Components.js)) :

```
...
const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function Components(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Header
        brand="Material Kit React"
        rightLinks={<HeaderLinks />}
        fixed
        color="transparent"
        changeColorOnScroll={{
          height: 400,
          color: "white"
        }}
        {...rest}
      />
      <Parallax image={require("assets/img/bg4.jpg")}>
        <div className={classes.container}>
        <GridContainer>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={6}>
              <div className={classes.brand}>
                <h1 className={classes.title}>Material Kit React.</h1>
                <h3 className={classes.subtitle}>
                  A test Badass Material-UI Kit based on Material Design.
                </h3>
              </div>
            </GridItem>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={6}>
            <div className={classes.brand}>
                <h1 className={classes.title}>Griditem 2</h1>
                <h3 className={classes.subtitle}>
                  A test Badass Material-UI Kit based on Material Design.
                </h3>
              </div>
            </GridItem>
          </GridContainer>
        </div>
      </Parallax>
...
```

GridContainer & GridItem both use material-ui/Grid.

Edit 1

After making the following changes :

```
...
<Parallax style={{ border: "solid 5px"}}>
  <div style={{height: "100%"}} className={classes.container}>
    <GridContainer>
...
```

& excluding the background image, now it looks like this :

[image: parallax with boder]

Apparently, when GridContainer contains 2 GridItems, the parent component(Parallax) is overflowing the Header.  Again, only in very small screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix it by adding another GridItem inside the GridContainer. This GridItem is the first item & has a minimum height equal to the header, thus preventing next item from going up.

```
    <Parallax style={{ border: "solid 5px"}}>
      <div style={{height: "100%"}} className={classes.container}>
        <GridContainer>
          <GridItem style={{minHeight: 80, border: "solid 5px"}}>
          </GridItem>
```